# How to search sub-directories for a file, and get the path?

Tags: javascript, arrays, directory, discord, fs

How would I go about doing this?

I am attempting to figure out how to search subdirectories of `./commands`, check all folders under it, for a file, and return the path to the file.

`//here` is where I wish the code to be.

```js
const categories = fs.readdirSync('./commands');

let commandFiles = [];
let commands = [];

for (let folder of categories) {
    let files = null;

    files = fs.readdirSync(`./commands/${folder}`).filter(
        file => file.endsWith('.js')
    );

    const newArray = commandFiles.concat(files)
    commandFiles = newArray
};

if (commandFiles) {
    for (let file of commandFiles) {
        commands.push(file)
    }
}

if (commands) {
    for (let name of commands) {
        // here

        config.commands.set(name, file)
    
        log.info(`[Commands] Loaded.. ${name} ✌️`)
    }
} else {
    log.info('[Commands] No commands have been found.')
}
```

Comment: I don't see any relation to Discord in this code. Please retag with your correct language/environment.

Comment: It’s for a discord bot, but yes alright.